# Get all categorical columns and exclude one specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I have a data frame named data. I want to select all the object and categorical data types excluding one column named test.

I have the below code but it is selecting all columns

```
| testid | color | age | mark |
+--------+-------+-----+------+
| a      | red   |  20 | pass |
| d      | green |  30 | fail |
| c      | blue  |  40 | pass |

data = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'red', 20, 'pass'], ['d', 'green', 30, 'fail'], ['c', 'blue', 40, 'pass']], columns=['testid', 'color', 'age', 'mark'])

for i in data.select_dtypes(include=['object','category']).columns:
    data[i]=le.fit_transform(data[i])
```

I want to transform all rows excluding `testid`

Comment: If one of the answers below helped, consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer#) it (green tick on left), so other users know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
cols = data.select_dtypes(include=['O', 'category']).columns.difference(['testid'])

for i in cols:
    data[i] = le.fit_transform(data[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a if statement like this:

```
for i in data.select_dtypes(include=['object','category']).columns:
    if i == 'testid':
        continue
    data[i]=le.fit_transform(data[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short solution:

```
cols = data.dtypes.isin(['O','category']).drop('testid').index

for i in cols:
    data[i] = le.fit_transform(data[i])
```